# Reduce wrongly returning infinity

Tags: javascript, reduce

when I try to use math power in reduce it's not working as expected and returns infinity

```js
const array1 = [1,2,3,4];

const initialValue = 0;
const sumWithInitial = array1.reduce(
  (a,b) => a + Math.pow(b, b + a),
  0
);

console.log(sumWithInitial);
```

but if there's only 1-3 numbers in arr1 it works as intended

Comment: Running the function with `[1,2,3]` yields 531450. In the fourth iteration the formula in your reduce function is 531450 + 4^(531450 + 4). The resulting number is simply to big and therefore being Infinity for JS.

Comment: Because the number is just *that big*? I'm not sure what you expect. On the last step `Math.pow(b, b + a)` has `b = 4` and `a` = 531450` so, it's raising 4 to the power of 531454.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the last iteration, you're exceeding the capacity of the JavaScript [number](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-data-types-and-values.html#sec-ecmascript-language-types-number-type) type (which is an [IEEE-754 double-precision binary floating point value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)). It has nothing to do with `reduce`, it's just that `Math.pow(4, 4 + 531450)` (the last value produced by your `reduce` loop) goes past the limit:

```js
console.log(Math.pow(4, 4 + 531450));
```

You can see when `pow` will do that via the [Number::exponentiate](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-data-types-and-values.html#sec-numeric-types-number-exponentiate) abstract operation in the specification (in the text, infinity is denoted by `+∞`, negative infinity by `-∞`). This is just a fact of trying to use a 64-bit value to try to represent a truly, truly, *truly* massive number.

If you need to deal with those kinds of magnitudes, and you only need integer values, you can use a `BigInt` [as Keldan Chapman points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75484547/157247).

Answer (score 3):

As others have explained, you get infinity due to going way above the limit. But if you want to get the actual result, you can use  [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) operations:

```js
const array1 = [1n, 2n, 3n, 4n];

const initialValue = 0n;
const sumWithInitial = array1.reduce(
    (a, b) => a + b**(b + a),
    initialValue
);

console.log(sumWithInitial.toString());
```

Comment: Good point about `BigInt`, though. Not sure why I didn't call that out.

Comment: Right, I misread the existing comments/post. Fixed here to avoid confusion.